# c# (UNITY) Получение данных из Json

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Пытаюсь получить данные из `Json` для дальнейшего использования.

Почему это не работает? Уже пол дня не могу понять.

c#

```
public class ItemsIni : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        InitializeItems();
    }

    void InitializeItems()
    {
        Init initItems = JsonUtility.FromJson<Init>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Languages/ru_RU.json"));
        Debug.Log(initItems.food.Apple.itemDescription.ToString());
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
    public string itemType { get; set; }
}

public class Food
{
    public Item Apple { get; set; }
    public Item Plum { get; set; }
}

public class Init
{
    public Food food { get; set; }
}
```

Json

```
{
 "Food": {
   "Apple": {
     "itemId": 0,
     "itemName": "Yabloko",
     "itemDescription": "Sladkoe",
     "itemType": "Eda"
   },
   "Plum": {
     "itemId": 1,
     "itemName": "Sliva",
     "itemDescription": "Kislaya",
     "itemType": "Eda"
   }
  }
 }
```

Unity error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ItemsIni.InitItems () (at Assets/GameScripts/ItemsIni.cs:15)
ItemsIni.Start () (at Assets/GameScripts/ItemsIni.cs:9)
```

Comment: Ваш же вопрос закрыли предыдущий, не уж то непонятно было, что у вас словарь в JSON? Также вы десериализуете сразу в `Food`, когда по структуре у вас еще есть объект выше (я про фигурные скобки над `"Food":`), где он в классах?

Comment: При добавлении класса поверх Food ничего не меняется. :(

Comment: Где это добавление? Код то обновите.

Comment: Обновил код, оно отдаёт ту же ошибку. :(

Comment: `public Food food` food с большой буквы надо как в json.

Comment: @aepot Без разницы, главное соответствие имени. По поводу кода, я вам (автору) уже говорил, что тут словарь! Закрыл предыдущий вопрос как дубликат и вы до сих пор этого не поняли. Удалите класс `Food` вообще, а в `Init` пропишите `public Dictionary<string, Item> Food { get; set; }`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1yx0gLX 

Не помогает T_T

Comment: [`FromJson`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html): Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; therefore the type you are creating must be supported by the serializer. It must be a plain class/struct **marked with the Serializable attribute**.

Comment: Перевести на русский или объяснить, что это значит, нужно?

Comment: Да я уже пихал его везде где можно `[System.Serializable]`, в примерах с простыми json его вообще не вставляют и всё работает T_T

Comment: Во-первых, можно просто `[Serializable]`, во-вторых, у вас не простой класс, а составной. Аттрибут нужно добавить над каждым классом с данными. Сначала убедитесь, что все сделано согласно документации, а потом ищите ошибки, не наоборот.

Comment: Ясно, в юнити ужасный парсер json, который [не умеет](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1479600/serialize-deserialize-dictionary-with-unity-serial.html) походу работать со словарями. Советую поставить JSON.NET (есть в ассетах), ну а сейчас тогда разбирайтесь почему не работает тот код, что у вас сейчас в ответе, может и правда нет атрибутов (JSON.NET и это [скушал](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A8pakt)).